# H2 Database result set is readonly

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

I'm getting the SQLNonTransientException error when trying to update one of my rows in a H2 database.

```
public static void setNewServiceInformationsToShown() {
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:" + Main.config_db_location,
            Main.config_db_username, Main.config_db_password)) {
        //read data from database
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM BCSTASKS_SERVICE");
        
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            if(rs.getString("Status").equals("Neu") && rs.getBoolean("wasShown") == false) {
                rs.updateBoolean("WASSHOWN", true);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error message already suggests that I should use conn.createStatement and set the ResultSet to CONCUR_UPDATABLE. The error occurs at the line with rs.updateBoolean(...);

Error Message:

> The result set is readonly. You may need to use conn.createStatement(.., ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE). [90140-210]

The problem is I don't know where and how I should use this method. In the same function or at the start of the program?

Comment: A few observations: if the question reflects your use case, then what you are trying to do can be accomplished WAY more efficiently with something like an `UPDATE .. SET wasShown=true WHERE status='Neu' AND wasShown=false`. Don't fetch the entire DB into memory just to to a conditional update. If you wanted to update 1 row, maybe `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` will work. And you can try the suggestion in the error message.

Comment: You haven't asked for an updatable result set. The default result set is CONCUR_READ_ONLY. You can request a different type using this variant of [`Connection.prepareStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,int,int)). That said, using an updatable result set for your use case sounds like the wrong approach. Using an `UPDATE` with a suitable where clause is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put update query for update data in database but you are going with select query that is the problem.

- `Select` query is used if you have to fetch data from database.
- `Update` query is used for update data in database where data already stored in database but you just overwrite data.

Here down is modified code:

```
public static void setNewServiceInformationsToShown() {
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:" + Main.config_db_location,
            Main.config_db_username, Main.config_db_password)) {
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE BCSTASKS_SERVICE SET wasShown = ? WHERE status = ? AND wasShown = ?");     
        stmt.setBoolean(1, true);
        stmt.setString(2, "Neu");
        stmt.setBoolean(3, false);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's downvoted because it doesn't answer your question. Your question is: How do I make `rs.updateThingie()` work.

Answer (score 2):

Most DB code I see doesn't attempt to use the fact that resultsets are updatable, and will instead fire off an additional UPDATE query, which works fine.

However, sure, H2 supports updateable resultsets too. However, some of the features that ResultSets have actually have quite a cost; the DB engine needs to do a boatload of additional bookkeeping to enable such features which have a performance cost. Lots of database queries are extremely performance sensitive, so by default you **do not** get the bookkeeping and therefore these features do not work. You need to enable them explicitly, that's what the error is telling you.

You're currently calling the 'wrong' `preparedStatement` method. You want the more extended one, where you pick and choose which additional bookkeeping you want H2 to do for you, in order to enable these things. You want [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)).

```java
conn.prepareStatement(
  "SELECT * FROM BCSTASKS_SERVICE",
  ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, // [edited]
  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

That `CONCUR_UPDATABLE` thing is just a flag you pass to say: Please do the bookkeeping so that I can call `.update`.

[edited] This used to read `0` before, but as @MarkRotteveel pointed out, that's not valid according to the documentation.

Comment: Using the value `0` as the second parameter will not work in compliant JDBC implementations as it is not a valid value for the resultSetType (_"Throws SQLException - if [..] the given parameters are not ResultSet constants indicating type and concurrency"_). Instead use the constant `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` (or `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` or `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`).

Comment: Oh, d'oh, good point. I'll edit the answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate query/prepareStatement for an update. In your case as far as I can see you need only one update query:

```
conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE BCSTASKS_SERVICE SET WASSHOWN=true where 
                       Status = 'Neu' and wasShown = false "
```